# How do I display same form in multiple pages using a single method in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a table with atrributes, and I'm displaying each attribute as a checkbox in html view. I want to show them in different pages, but I don't want to make different functions for each category. Is there an efficient way to do so? Here is what I tried so far.

```
def questions(request):
# start session page for the user to test
questions = Attribute.objects.all()
realistic = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=1)
investigative = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=2)
artistic = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=3)
social = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=4)
enterprising = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=5)
conventional = Attribute.objects.filter(holland_code=6)


left = [realistic, investigative, artistic, social, enterprising, conventional]
for attribute in left:
    # get all the values form the form submitted
    if request.method == "POST":
        # THIS WILL GET ALL THE RECOMMENDAITONS
        rAttributes = request.POST.getlist('realistic')
        print(rAttributes)
        return render(request, "main/questions.html", {"questions": attribute})

context = {
    "questions": realistic,

}
return render(request, 'main/questions.html', context)
```

This is my html template to display the checkboxes

```
            <form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-check">
                {% for question in realistic %}
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1" name="realistics" value="{{ question.attribute_name }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">{{ question.attribute_name }}</label>
                <br>
                {% endfor %}  
            </div>

              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Next">
        </form>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking here, but you certainly can define the checkboxes as individual templates and then include them as necessary into any template that you are rendering, so that you don't repeat repeat yourself yourself ...

Comment: I have a table called Attribute, and I have bunch of attributes in the table under foreignkey of another table. I want to display attributes under each foreignkey as a checkbox with each foreignkey having its own html form. Then I want to save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the form to the base template and extend that template so it'll be available everywhere.

or you could create a class based view and add a post request

```
class InsterViewNameHere(View):
  def post(request, self, id=None, *args, **kwargs):
    #form logic and context here 
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

To not have to repeat the same post function for every view or class-based-view, you could create a Mixin view

```
class ObjectnameMixin(object):
  model = ClassModel
  form = formname
  def post_form(self):
    return form
```